# Querying a Nested Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying my hand at querying a `NESTED TABLE` using `PL/SQL` (which I'm told by several sources is possible) but I keep getting the error message: **ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete.**..

I don't understand why it won't let me do it...I've already established that the `dados` variable has content in it... I output its `.count` and it's not empty.. Could someone shed me a light on this??

Thanks is advance...

```
procedure PREENCHE_CURSOR_ESTRANG_TOTAL(O_CURSOR out t_refcur) is    

  c_nips t_refcur;

  dados T_PONTOS := T_PONTOS();--nested table instantiating..

  i number;

  nip number(8);

  gerador_de_nips varchar2(600) := 'a biG SQL QUERY nobody needs to know about =P';


begin
    i := 1;
    open c_nips for gerador_de_nips;
    loop
        dados.extend;
        fetch c_nips into nip;
        exit when c_nips%notfound;
        dados(i) := RETORNA_PONTOS(nip);
        i := i+1;

    end loop;


    close c_nips;

    open O_CURSOR for select * from table(dados); /*WHY*/


end PREENCHE_CURSOR_ESTRANG_TOTAL;
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of `T_PONTOS`?  In particular, is it declared in SQL or PL/SQL?  Additionally, `RENTORNA_PONTOS` appears not to be defined anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand the specific error you are getting, but generally you need to include an explicit cast to the appropriate type in the SQL statement:

```
open O_CURSOR for select * from table(CAST(dados AS t_pontos));
```

This is because the statement is handed off from PL/SQL to the SQL engine for processing, and it has no information about the type of the variable beyond it being user-defined.

Also, this only works if the type (`t_pontos`) is declared at the schema level, i.e. with a `CREATE TYPE` statement.  If it is declared somewhere in PL/SQL code, e.g. in a package specification, the SQL engine cannot access the type definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your cursor in the beginning of your procedure and open it in the body of your procedure.