# ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete

Tags: sql, oracle

I have package with Period and TableOfPeriod types:

```
  TYPE Period
  IS RECORD
  (   StartPeriod  Date,
      EndPeriod    Date
  );

  TYPE TableOfPeriod
  IS TABLE OF Period;
```

and in this package I have three simple function:

```
  FUNCTION Temp1
  RETURN TableOfPeriod IS
    returnedValue TableOfPeriod := TableOfPeriod();
  BEGIN
    returnedValue.extend(1);
    returnedValue(1).StartPeriod := sysdate-100;
    returnedValue(1).EndPeriod := sysdate;
    RETURN returnedValue;
  END Temp1;

FUNCTION CalculateFine
  return VARCHAR2
  IS
  freewillLockTableRP         TableOfPeriod:=TableOfPeriod();
  compulsoryLockTableRP       TableOfPeriod:=TableOfPeriod();

  BEGIN

  --for testing
      compulsoryLockTableRP:=Temp1();
      FOR i IN compulsoryLockTableRP.FIRST..compulsoryLockTableRP.LAST LOOP
        IF(((compulsoryLockTableRP(i).EndPeriod - compulsoryLockTableRP(i).StartPeriod)>1)) THEN
            BEGIN
--              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Hello world');
              SELECT T111.StartPeriod StartPeriod,
                     T111.EndPeriod   EndPeriod
                    bulk collect into freewillLockTableFull
              FROM TABLE(DistributeDaysByPeriods(compulsoryLockTableRP, 5)) T111;
          END;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      /*SELECT T111.StartPeriod StartPeriod,
             T111.EndPeriod   EndPeriod
--          BULK COLLECT INTO compulsoryLockTableRP
            bulk collect into freewillLockTableFull
      FROM TABLE(DistributeDaysByPeriods(compulsoryLockTableRP, 5)) T111;*/
  --===========

  --SOME OTHER PROCESSING


  RETURN 'Ok ' 
         ||  '#r';




  EXCEPTION
    WHEN No_Data_Found THEN return 'No data found#g';
--    WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN SQLERRM;

  END CalculateFine;
```

When I execute this function, I have next error:

> "ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete ORA-06512:
>   at "MyPackageName", line 1181 ORA-06512: at line 1
>   21700. 00000 -  "object does not exist or is marked for delete""

where 1181 line is a line with Select statement of CalculateFine function. Can anybody tell me, whats wrong and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying a Nested Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421581/querying-a-nested-table)

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have in the same folder where your package is located a file with the same name but with an extention *.~sql (e.g.: *your_file_name.~sql*). I had the same error but after I have deleted an *.~sql file I could compile my package without ORA errors.

Comment: the question about runtime error rather than compile one