# Object not exists error while using TABLE expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Here is my code: Quite Straight forward..

```
create or replace package types
as
   type rec is record
   (
     employee_id NUMBER,
     fname varchar2(20)  
    );
   type tab_rec is table of rec;
   type tab_numbers is table of number;
   type tab_chars is table of varchar2(10);

 end types;
 /

 create or replace 
 function get_employees_rec
 (
   O_error_msg IN OUT varchar2,
   L_access_tab OUT types.tab_chars
   )
   return boolean
   as
--o_access_tab types.tab_chars;
cursor c_rec is 
select first_name from employees;
begin
     open c_rec;
     fetch c_rec bulk collect into L_access_tab;
     close c_rec;
     return true;
exception
when others  then
      O_error_msg:=substr(sqlerrm,1,100);
      return false;
end;

/
declare
  O_error_msg varchar2(100);
  L_access types.tab_chars;
begin
    if get_employees_rec(O_error_msg,L_access)=FALSE then
        dbms_output.put_line('Got you');
    end if;

for rec in(select * from employees e,TABLE(L_access) f where value(f)=e.first_name) 
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line(rec.first_name);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

However I am getting the error :

**ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete**
ORA-06512: at line 9
21700. 00000 -  "object does not exist or is marked for delete"
*Cause:    User attempted to perform an inappropriate operation to
           an object that is non-existent or marked for delete.
           Operations such as pinning, deleting and updating cannot be
           applied to an object that is non-existent or marked for delete.
*Action:   User needs to re-initialize the reference to reference an
           existent object or the user needs to unmark the object.

What is the reason behind this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying a Nested Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421581/querying-a-nested-table)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access those types from an external package like that, rather create them as database objects:

```
create or replace type rec is object (
  employee_id NUMBER,
  fname varchar2(20));

create or replace  type tab_rec is table of rec;
```

etc.